# SSL Startup from 1and1 shows warning in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I am using free SSL Startup from my hosting provider 1and1. But, now it shows warning in chrome. How can I resolve this issue?

> The SSL certificate used to load resources from website will be
>   distrusted in M70. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from
>   loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for
>   more information.

Answer (score 1):

1and1 will automatically replace all certificates before the 13.09.2018 deadline but you can replace them in advance.

This 1and1 help page contains the details.

https://help.1and1.co.uk/ssl-certificates-c85276/administration-c85278/ssl-certificate-managed-by-1and1-c85280/replace-symantec-ssl-certificates-a793476.html

Answer (score 0):

The link included in what you cite clearly says what the problem is, i.e. that the issuer of your certificate (the certificate authority (CA)) will no longer be trusted. This means that you need to get a certificate from another CA which is trusted.

A widely used CA for free certificate is [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). See [Install a Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate on a 1&1 Cloud Server with Plesk](https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/networking/ssl-certificates/install-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-on-a-11-cloud-server-with-plesk/) for how to use Let's Encrypt with your 1&1 server.

Answer (score 0):

https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html

> #### Information For Site Operators
>
> Starting with Chrome 66, Chrome will remove trust in Symantec-issued certificates issued prior to June 1, 2016. Chrome 66 is currently scheduled to be released to Chrome Beta users on March 15, 2018 and to Chrome Stable users around April 17, 2018.
>
> If you are a site operator with a certificate issued by a Symantec CA prior to June 1, 2016, then prior to the release of Chrome 66, you will need to replace the existing certificate with a new certificate from any Certificate Authority trusted by Chrome."

As the Symantec certificate for login.salesforce.com dated back to 03/03/2016, the current Chrome Canary (V66) not accepting it.